# How join two table or writing custom queries in Datatable php?

Tags: php, mysql, join, datatable

I am using datatable to list data as server side scripting.

```
    // DB table to use
$table = 'enquiry';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'enquiry_id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array(
        'db' => 'enquiry_date',
        'dt' => 0,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date('jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array('db' => 'parent_name', 'dt' => 1),
    array('db' => 'child_name', 'dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'mobile', 'dt' => 3),
    array('db' => 'emirate', 'dt' => 4),
    array('db' => 'remarks', 'dt' => 5),
    array('db' => 'enquiry_status_id', 'dt' => 6),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db' => 'lsn',
    'host' => ''
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( './server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns)
);
```

This is my php server side scripting and working very fine for single table.

I want to join two table while listing table row. But I couldn't find any option for joining tables or writing custom queries.

how can I join table if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

here two table keyid same field and other field fetch

```
$sql_t="SELECT tabkey.keyid, table1.value, table2.value
FROM
(SELECT table1.keyid FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.keyid FROM table2) as tabkey
LEFT JOIN
table1 on tabkey.keyid = table1.keyid
LEFT JOIN
table2 on tabkey.keyid = table2.keyid;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: open ssp.class.php

Step 2: locate this line.....               FROM '$table'

Step 3: remove single quotation....             FROM $table

Step 4: do the same to the other one .....       FROM   '$table' "

```
                                     FROM    $table"
```

Step 5: you can now add subquery to $table

example   $table="(select * from my_list join...)";

Step 6: Celebrate =)